# How to make color patterns in css?

Tags: html, css

[image]

To achieve this design I created a div of certain size.
In above image background color of the div is red and green is used as smoke on top of it in some pattern.
How can I create such patterns ?
What are different ways to achieve this in CSS ?

```
<div id="canvas" style="background-color:red;">

</div>
```

This is all I could do. I created a similar color pattern (the pattern of green) on photoshop. Placed it on this div then tried to change the color of that pattern. But it didnot reflect any changes.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/stripes-css/

Comment: If you save your Photoshop file with a transparent background, you can use multiple backgrounds in CSS. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_backgrounds.asp

Comment: You need to come up with more than just a `div`. Study how `canvas` work and make an effort, so we know you know something, or else this will be quite pointless

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra Considering this user been around for 3 years, they should know better than to ask someone else to do their work. Btw, I didn't down vote, and as you can see, I comment and vote to close.

Comment: @LGSon, I do think that approach includes some assumptions about the users previous use of the site, and doubt 4 people manage to get a good overview of that within one minute of the user posting the question.. I'm not commenting on the validity of the downvotes btw, just on the way they seem to have come about..

Comment: Creating abstract shapes like a wisp of cloud or smoke is next to impossible with CSS. Anything you can come up with will certainly not be as clean, effective, or maintainable as doing it in another, more appropriate language. Even SVG might be better, but you're most likely to find satisfaction in outcome via JavaScript. There are existing JS libraries for particle and smoke visuals.

Comment: @MathijsFlietstra I get puzzled with that too...sometimes a similar _lacking enough info_ question in a matter of minutes get +3 instead of -3, which would be more appropriate. In many cases I don't think there is more to it than just that, if it looks _good_, upvote, if _bad_, down vote. ... And don't forget, many votes gives badges :) and spending time writing comments _only_ higher quality posts.

Answer (score 1):

This kind of color pattern you can made in **SVG** ( Illustrator )  and then you can use it at your project like this

```
 <div class="mySvg">
   <svg>
     <use x="0" y="0" xlink:href="#color"></use>
   </svg>
 </div>
```

[Details](https://gist.github.com/momin-ctg/2bed538838c49978081fa622654657f4)

Comment: The question asks how to do this in CSS.

Comment: The author of this answer knows more than the OP. The mistake (if there is one) is not an answer explaining how to achieve the desired effect in SVG, - the mistake is asking how to achieve it in CSS.

Comment: @Momin  SVG will work too, but I want to generate these dynamically based on input colors.