# How to generate color based patterns dynamically for web?

Tags: javascript, php, css, svg, gd

My previous question:
[How to make color patterns in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45916941/how-to-make-color-patterns-in-css?noredirect=1#comment78801385_45916941)

[image]

I want to generate color patterns as in above image. This image has red as background and green on top of it in a pattern. I want to use the same pattern for the upper color. This image should be generated based on user input of color codes or color names.

In my previous questions some users said it's impossible to do in css. Below is link to example website which has implemented this in css.

https://www.sleekwristbands.com/customize/

Goto this webpage and on step 3 choose checkbox named swirl and a preferred color combination like Red-Green in above image.

Scroll to next step and it displays the same preview.

This is implemented on css.

Some sites have implemented on SVG too. Any solutions will work for me, if its difficult to achieve in css what is more efficient way to do this? on which direction should I proceed ?

Some sites have implemented using PHP GD library.

Example : https://www.wristbandtoday.com/debossed-custom-silicone-wristbands

Are there any libraries for GD for these stuffs(color patterns, color masks) ?

One user generated SVG code for the pattern 
https://gist.github.com/momin-ctg/2bed538838c49978081fa622654657f4

But is this way suitable for generating dynamic content as there can be numerous combination of color codes.

Comment: The example website was not just done with CSS. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMrx9.png

Comment: The example site actually uses CSS mask, then a bunch of semi-transparent images like this one: https://www.sleekwristbands.com/wp-content/themes/swb/images/wc-swirl-smoke-pattern2.png

Comment: Please note, that the CSS solution of this site uses experimental -webkit prefixed styles, so it actually does not work in Edge, IE or even Firefox, so this is not really a "best practice" at all

Comment: @naththedeveloper if they used images, then that means it's not actually done in CSS. The patterns that is.

I don't believe there's a way to recreate this pattern with just CSS. You really need your own resources